# C# Оверлей а-ля Steam

Tags: c#, .net

Требуется сделать оверлей а-ля оверлей в steam (оверлей - то, что появляется при нажатии Shift+Tab) или Origin, но ничего толкового о том, как это сделать гугл мне не выдал. Каким образом это можно реализовать, или хотя бы в каком направлении двигатся?

P.S. Повторюсь, гугл ничего толкового не высказал

Answer (score 1):

Так если вы пишите игру с помощью directx то и воспользуйтесь ею. У всего фона убавляете яркость выводите область на нее лепите текстуры и какие-то кнопки. Я бы делал так.

Comment: Я не пишу игру, написано же, оверлей а-ля steam, он должен использоватся с  почти любой игрой на dx

Answer (score 0):

1. Как на счет еще одного окна, без границ и т.п., который будет поверх остальныx?
2. Через WinAPI кажется можно установить, чтобы некоторое окно было внутри указанного. На изусть не помню метод :)

Comment: Не подойдёт, игра запущена на фуллскрин и отрисовка через directx

Answer (score 0):

Делайте перехват сочетания клавиш и лепите то что вам надо внутри.